# SharedPreferences never get key default value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

This is my code:

```
package com.example.scheda_ais;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText degustatore;
    Button completa;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    String generalita;
    String appoggio;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("il_sottoscritto",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    degustatore = findViewById(R.id.degustatore);

    completa = findViewById(R.id.completa);
    completa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            generalita = degustatore.getText().toString();

            if(generalita != ""){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putString("generalita", generalita);
                editor.commit();
            }


            appoggio = sharedPref.getString("generalita", "vuoto");
            Log.d("generalita", appoggio);
        }
    });
}
```

When I press the Button with an empty EditText (no input at all), nothing is printed by Log, while Log should print *"generalita" + "vuoto"*.
Why *String appoggio* is empty?
If I input something in EditText, Log prints correctly *"generalita" + appoggio*.
Please someone help me. Thanks.

Comment: you should correctly compare string by using "equals" method like this : if(!generalita.equals(""))

Comment: @SebastienRieu, yup that's one thing. But now I suspect OP actually wrote an empty string value for the key `generalita`, so unless the app is uninstalled or another value is written, LogCat will obviously print nothing (because 'nothing' is the value that's contained for that key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using != to compare your string you are comparing "object instance" but "" and generalita string is not the same object so you are entering in the if and put "" to your preference so the preference is not null when you log it and the default value is not print.

that's what appens:

```
sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("il_sottoscritto",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
degustatore = findViewById(R.id.degustatore);

completa = findViewById(R.id.completa);
completa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        generalita = degustatore.getText().toString();

        // generalita instance and "" intance are not equal so the trest will pass
        if(generalita != ""){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            // here you're putting "" to your preference
            editor.putString("generalita", generalita);
            editor.commit();
        }

        // sharedPref.getString("generalita", "vuoto") return ""
        appoggio = sharedPref.getString("generalita", "vuoto");
        Log.d("generalita", appoggio);
    }
});
```

you should do like that

```
completa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        generalita = degustatore.getText().toString();

        if(!generalita.equals("")){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("generalita", generalita);
            editor.commit();
        }

        appoggio = sharedPref.getString("generalita", "vuoto");
        Log.d("generalita", appoggio);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank u very much sir. U werw right: my comparing expression war wrong.

Answer (score 1):

change this  `appoggio = sharedPref.getString("generalita", "vuoto");`

to `appoggio = sharedPref.getString("generalita", "");`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with what you wrote.

As @SebastienRieu said correctly
the first one , you can't do == for Strings in java.

You need to write:

```
if(!"".equals(generalita)){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("generalita", generalita);
    editor.commit();
}
```

And the 2nd one, you said you were expecting "generalita" + "vuoto"
However in this code:

```
appoggio = sharedPref.getString("generalita", "vuoto");
Log.d("generalita", appoggio);
```

in the Log the first word "generalita" is not text printed in the log, but rather a TAG that is filterable. If you want to see "generalita vuoto", then you'd have to put both on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `generalita != ""`, by `!generalita.isEmpty()` to check the length of your String.